# Reason for the "class members are put in ascending order" rule?

Tags: c++

C++98 had the rule:

> If two pointers point to nonstatic data members of the same object, or to subobjects or array elements of
>   such members, recursively, the pointer to the later declared member **compares greater** provided the two
>   members are **not separated by an access-specifier label** (11.1) and provided their class is not a union.

This specifies that members should be put in ascending order, provided there is no intervening access-specifier.

Later, this rule become more strict in C++11:

> If two pointers point to non-static data members of the same object, or to subobjects or array elements
>   of such members, recursively, **the pointer to the later declared member compares greater provided the
>   two members have the same access control** (Clause 11) and provided their class is not a union.

Here, all members with the same access specifier should be put in ascending order.

I have two questions:

- why does the rule become more strict in C++11?
- why do we have this rule in the first place? For standard-layout classes, this rule makes sense. But is it useful for non standard-layout classes? One obvious drawback is that the compiler is not allowed to reorder all members freely so the class could take less space (padding can be reduced if data members are sorted by decreasing alignment).

Comment: As to why the rule exists in the first place, the ARM (p. 242) says that the rule allows an implementation to pursue a strategy of minimal recompilation.  For example, if the private data is changed, previously compiled code that only uses the public data does not need to be recompiled.   The ARM is the document that was written to guide development of the first C++ standard (aka, now, C++98).   If the compiler was allowed to arbitrarily reorder all members (e.g. for padding) it would mean that ANY change of class members would force recompilation.

Comment: @Peter: that's only true, if public data is put at the end. Do you know any implementation which supports that fine-grain dependency tracking? All the build tools I know uses file times when it decides what to recompile.

Comment: It's actually true if the implementation can organise private, protected, and public sections in some (fixed, compiler-specific) order. Several versions of MSVC support a minimal rebuild option, which does essentially that  (although, IIRC, deprecated in recent versions of MSVC). Since about 2010, a long term development goal of clang is to support "incremental recompilation", which (among other things) includes this. In any event, you asked why the rule exists, and I gave you a reference to a source. Your wanting to argue the rule isn't needed doesn't change the history behind it.

Comment: @Peter: but then this needs a separate, hidden offset field, which points to the public section, right? And I don't want to argue at all. I just consider this a weak feature compared to the inefficiency it causes. It simply doesn't worth to add this to the *standard* because of this. It could be just a feature of an implementation, it shouldn't be a requirement by the standard.

Comment: @Peter: the page you referred to more-or-less has the answer to my question (it's just not the part you referred to). I added it as an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the second is more strict. The first is.

"not separated by an access-specifier label" implies "have the same access control" obviously.

But you may have two members in the same class both separated by an access specifier, ie:

```
public:
    int m1;
public:
    int m2;
```

First clause is not verified but second is. Thus first is more restrictive.

Thus first spec is more syntactic and the second more semantic.

The second also let compiler rearrange members by access category, thus let it have some "global" layout strategy by access category, ie a chunk for privates, another one for protected and a third one for publics.

Comment: With C++98, the compiler can put `m1` and `m2` freely. With C++11, it doesn't (`m2` must be put after `m1`). So C++11 is more restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quote from the Annotated C++ Reference Manual, page 242:

> The requirement that members not separated by access specifier labels be allocated in the order in which they are declared provides compatibility with existing C code.

It seems that back then (1990), the POD concept hadn't been invented yet, and this rule provided compatibility with C code.

But I wonder, that C++98 (which has the POD concept) why still has the ordering rule for all type of classes. PODs are intended to serve the compatibility with C code, the general ordering rule doesn't add anything more to it.